# This code works but it's too verbose, how do i make it shorter?

Tags: php

This code actually works but it's a little bit too verbose, i would like to shrink it but i can't find a solution...

Edit: further explanation:  $keywords is an array with a lot of single words extracted from a text. In $text i would like to put al lemmas i can create using adjacent words. Let's say my original text is "I like green apples", in $keywords i have "I","like","green","apples". In $text i will have then "I like", "I like green", "I like green apples" ...

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($keywords);$i++) {
        $text[] = $keywords[$i];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1]." ".$keywords[$i+2];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1]." ".$keywords[$i+2]." ".$keywords[$i+3];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1]." ".$keywords[$i+2]." ".$keywords[$i+3]." ".$keywords[$i+4];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1]." ".$keywords[$i+2]." ".$keywords[$i+3]." ".$keywords[$i+4]." ".$keywords[$i+5];
        $text[] = $keywords[$i]." ".$keywords[$i+1]." ".$keywords[$i+2]." ".$keywords[$i+3]." ".$keywords[$i+4]." ".$keywords[$i+5]." ".$keywords[$i+6];    
    }
```

Comment: why dont u tell us what u are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use two for-loops in order to create such a list:

```
<?php

$keywords = explode(' ', 'k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6 k7');
$text = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i++) {
        $line = array();

        for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
                $line[] = $keywords[$j];
        }

        $text[] = implode(' ', $line);
}

print_r($text);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => k1
    [1] => k1 k2
    [2] => k1 k2 k3
    [3] => k1 k2 k3 k4
    [4] => k1 k2 k3 k4 k5
    [5] => k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6
    [6] => k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6 k7
)
*/
```

This code should work with arbitrary length array.